# Using CrossListQueryInfo, no results?

Tags: 2007

I have the following snippet of code that works in MOSS 2007, but when used against SP 2010, no items are returned. The 2010 instance is a test upgrade of the content database from the 2007 farm.

Has something changed in 2010?

```
CrossListQueryInfo q = new CrossListQueryInfo();
                    q.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"104\"/>";
                    q.Query = "<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ContentType\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">External Announcement</Value></Eq><Or><IsNull><FieldRef Name=\"Expires\" /></IsNull><Gt><FieldRef Name=\"Expires\" /><Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Today /></Value></Gt></Or></And></Where>";
                    q.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";
                    q.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><FieldRef Name=\"ContentType\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Expires\" Nullable=\"TRUE\" /><FieldRef Name=\"FileRef\" /><FieldRef Name=\"EncodedAbsUrl\" />";
                    q.RowLimit = 5;
                    q.WebUrl = "/";
                    q.UseCache = true;
                    CrossListQueryCache cache = new CrossListQueryCache(q);
                    dt = cache.GetSiteData(site, CrossListQueryCache.ContextUrl());
                    staffAnnouncements.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must be something not quite right with the content type after the upgrade. Managed to get it working by changing the CAML query to retrieve the content type based upon the ID starting with the required guid.

Comment: please dont place comments as answers! Use comment fields or edit your question. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Has your "External ContentType" migrated over ok?

Otherwise, does your query work without the Content type filter that you have there?

Answer (score 0):

Even a "simple" query such as that below results in no items returned :(

```
                    CrossListQueryInfo q = new CrossListQueryInfo();
                    q.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate=\"104\" />";
                    q.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /></OrderBy>";
                    q.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";
                    q.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />";
                    q.RowLimit = 5;
                    q.WebUrl = "/";
                    q.UseCache = true;
                    CrossListQueryCache cache = new CrossListQueryCache(q);
                    dt = cache.GetSiteData(site, CrossListQueryCache.ContextUrl());
```

Comment: Doh, ignore that, I forgot to bind the query to the Repeater control!! OK that code above returns all announcements, if I change it back to retrieve a Content Type by name it still returns nothing.